# How to update a line attribute in PostGIS using an attribute from the polygon in which it is contained?

Tags: postgis, sql, query

I have a road dataset which I want to update using the speed information from the state polygon in which it's contained.

```
for all roads (line) within a state (polygon)
if the road speed is null
road speed becomes state speed
```

My preference is to use Contains or Within and only attribute speed information to the road if the entire line geometry is completely inside a polygon.

How do I do this in PostGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query translates your question into a PostGIS query which sets the default state speed to all roads with `NULL` speed completely within a state.

```sql
UPDATE roads 
SET speed = states.speed
FROM states
WHERE ST_Within(roads.geom, states.geom) AND 
roads.speed IS NULL
```